# Find local minimum in n x n matrix in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, search

So, this is not my home work question, but it is taken from an ungraded homework of the coursera course on algorithms and data structures (which is now complete).

You are given an n by n grid of distinct numbers. A number is a local minimum if it is smaller than all of its neighbors. (A neighbor of a number is one immediately above, below, to the left, or the right. Most numbers have four neighbors; numbers on the side have three; the four corners have two.) Use the divide-and-conquer algorithm design paradigm to compute a local minimum with only O(*n*) comparisons between pairs of numbers. (Note: since there are *n*<sup>2</sup> numbers in the input, you cannot afford to look at all of them. Hint: Think about what types of recurrences would give you the desired upper bound.)

Since the numbers are not in any order, I don't see how we can get away with any thing but O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) comparisons.

Comment: Do it in `O(log(n))` or `O(n)` ?

Comment: There are n^2 elements, so O(n) will be awesome. Of course, O(log(n)) would be brilliant if possible

Comment: Also we need to be careful about what `n` is.  Initially you said `n` was the number of rows and columns meaning there are `n^2` numbers.  Each number has roughly 4 neighbors so there are roughly `4*n^2/2` pairs, yes?  Meaning in terms of `m` being the number of pairs if we are supposed to do it in `O(m)` then that's `O(n^2)`.  Also we're just computing a single local minimum - not the least element?

Comment: Yes, there might be some double counting in the 4*n^2/2, but I think it is still O(n^2). And yeah, we just want a single local minimum, not global.

Comment: I have edited the title of this question to match its content. There is nothing about "log n" in here at all. The question is actually very  clear. I don't know the answer yet, though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We can adapt Words Like Jared's answer, by looking at how it can go wrong.

The idea in that answer -- which is a good one -- is to "roll downhill". This just means, if you are on an element, check if it is a local minimum. If so, you are done; otherwise, step to the smallest of its nearest neighbors. Eventually this must terminate because every step is to a smaller element, and that cannot go on forever in a finite array.

The problem with this approach is that the "rolling" can meander all over the place:

```
20 100 12  11 10 100  2
19 100 13 100  9 100  3
18 100 14 100  8 100  4
17  16 15 100  7   6  5
```

If you start at the upper left and "roll downhill", you will visit around half of the elements in the array. That is too many, so we have to constrain it a bit.

Start by examining the middle column and middle row. Find the smallest element among all of those and start there.

Roll one step "downhill" from there to enter one of the four quadrants. You will enter one of the quadrants, because the adjacent elements in the middle column and/or row are larger, so only one of the two adjacent quadrants could be "downhill".

Now consider what would happen if you "rolled downhill" from there. Obviously, you would eventually reach a local minimum. (We will not actually do this because it would take too long.) **But**, in the course of rolling around, you would never leave that quadrant... Because to do so, you would have to cross either the middle column or middle row, and none of those elements are smaller than where you started. Therefore that quadrant contains a local minimum somewhere.

Thus, in linear time, we have identified a quadrant that must contain a local minimum, and we have cut n in half. Now just recurse.

This algorithm takes time 2n + 2n/2 + 2n/4 + ..., which equals 4n, which is O(n) so we are done.

Interestingly, we did not use "rolling downhill" very much at all, except for the critical part: Proving that the algorithm works.

[Update]

As [Incassator points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24461101/768469), this answer is not entirely correct, because after you "just recurse" you might roll out of the quadrant again...

The simplest fix is to find the smallest element among the middle row, middle column, *and boundary* before you "roll downhill".

Comment: We're looking for *a* local minimum not *the* minimum.

Comment: Why does considering the boundary change anything? When we recurse and find that the minimum is on the boundary of the submatrix, we still don't know if it's a local minimum for the entire matrix since we don't have the element beneath it when we recurse.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer by Nemo is nice but not fully correct:

> Thus, in linear time, we have identified a quadrant that must contain a local minimum, and we have cut n in half. Now just recurse.

I am referring to "just recurse" bit. The problem is we cannot do that directly because on next iteration we might find a local minimum which is *not* a local minimum for original grid (x below means some arbitrary large numbers):

```
 x  x 39  x  x 50  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x 38  x  x 49  x  x  x  x  x
37 36 33 34 35 48  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x 32  x  1 10  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x 31  x  x 47  x  x  x  x  x
46 45 30 44 43 60 51 52 53 54 55
 x  x  2  x  x 56  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x 57  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x 58  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x 59  x  x  x  x  x
```

At first iteration we find 10 to be a minimum of middle row and middle column. We go to the left (as 1 is less than 10). So our next iteration is on upper-left quadrant. But now minimum of middle row and column is going to be 31 (or 30 if quadrant's borders are considered to be part of it). You will then conclude that it is a local minimum. But it is not for the full grid.

We can rectify this unfortunate defect in variety of ways. I solved it like this:

At each iteration in addition to the grid itself we keep track of current *minimum candidate* (that is the 1 in the example above after    first iteration; in the initial state we can say minimum candidate is    plus infinity). We calculate minimum of middle row and column and    compare it to minimum candidate. If the latter is smaller we recurse    into the quadrant *containing minimum candidate*. Otherwise we forget    previous candidate and only then check whether new middle row/column    minimum is actually a local minimum. And if not then recurse as usual    to whatever quadrant we slope down from it (and track new minimum    candidate).

Alternatively, you can modify the procedure as described in [this    presumably MIT lecture](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/spring11/lectures/lec02.pdf): at each iteration instead of looking at    middle row/column you can look at middle row/column *and* grid    boundary. Then the algorithm once again is correct.

You choose which way you like.

Comment: How do you we resolve the ties, when there are 2 local minimums in a matrix.
For E.g
matrix of {{9,10}, {15,8}} has two local minimums viz. 9 (first element 0,0) and 8 (last element (1,1))

Comment: @chebus You are required to find _a_ local minimum. Whichever one you happen to find. So if during an iteration of the algorithm you have multiple minimal elements you proceed with any one of those.

Comment: Why does considering the grid boundary change anything? In the example you gave, if the boundary has 100s in every one of its spaces, then when we recurse on the top left quadrant we still find that 30 is a local minimum of the submatrix, when really it's not(because of the 2 beneath of the 30)

Comment: @BigBear 10 is still the minimum of the mid row/col and boundary. So next recursion is the right down part of the first quadrant.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is actually really easy.

Turn the problem into 3-D one to see why the algorithm works.  Put the matrix on a table.  Pretend there are pillars extending out of each cell and that the height of the pillar is directly proportional to its value.  Put a ball on any pillar. Have the ball always fall onto the adjacent pillar that is the lowest altitude until it is at a local minimum.

Comment: This gives the right answer, but it is too slow. The ball might roll down the first column, two steps right, up the third column, two steps right, down the fifth column... All the way until it lands in the opposite corner. (It is easy to construct an example where this happens.) That touches half the squares, and compares around four times that amount, which is O(n^2), not O(n).

Comment: Sounds good, but is it O(log(N))? Probably, but it is worth adding complexity analysis to the answer I think.

Comment: This solution is `O(n^2)` I believe.  No matter where you start your nemisis can devise a walled maze that takes you through half or so of the cells.

Comment: @bcorso: Fair enough, but in this case a worst-case O(n) algorithm actually exists. See my answer. (Also, when a problem like this says O(n) algorithm, I believe "worst case" is implied. If they are talking averages, they usually say so.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how you divide and conquer it.

1) Divide the n x n matrix into four n/2 x n/2 sub matrices.

2) Keep dividing the sub matrices recursively until you end up with a 2 x 2 matrix

3) Check if any element of 2 x 2 matrix is a local Minimum.

Recurrence equation is : **T(n) = 4*T(n/2) + O(1)**

4*T(n/2) for 4 n/2 x n/2 sub matrices and O(1) for checking if 2 x 2 sub matrix has a local minimum

Master theorem says this is a **O(n^2)** worst case bound.

But I think we can get a best case **O(n)** bound,

(" RED ALERT! ---BEST CASE IS BOGUS, JUST BOGUS---RED ALERT!").

if we exit the recursion stack after we have have found a local minimum in step 3.

Pseudocode:

```
private void FindlocalMin(matrix,rowIndex,colIndex,width){
    if(width == 1){ checkForLocalMinimum(matrix,rowIndex,colIndex); return;} //2x2 matrix
    FindlocalMin(matrix,rowIndex,colIndex,width/2);  
    FindlocalMin(matrix, (rowIndex + (width/2) + 1) ,colIndex,width/2);
    FindlocalMin(matrix,rowIndex, (colIndex + (width/2) + 1) ,width/2);
    FindlocalMin(matrix,(rowIndex + (width/2) + 1), (colIndex + (width/2) + 1) ,width/2);
}

private void checkForLocalMinimum(.........){
    if(found Local Minimum in 2x2 matrix){ exit recursion stack;} 
}
```

Here is a [java implementation](https://bitbucket.org/candidust/randomprograms/src/74eae37bb1b4672be38d64b370dbdf8b2bb8c465/nXn_Matrix_Local_Minimum.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: "we can get a best case O(n)" is there way to prove the best case?

Answer (score 1):

Code Works for 3*3 or greater matrix, developed as per exercise of Algorithms 4th Edition Book Exercise .

It works as Following

1. Look for middle row of given matrix and find minimum out of it
2. for that minimum look for above and below element to ensure that it's local minimum
3. if not restrict search matrix by

   1. Row : choose half side of row in which the lesser element than middle row's element is.
   2. colmun : choose the index at which minimum in the row was found.
4. Repeat step 1-3

public class MinimumOfMatrix {

```
private static int findLocalMinimum(int[][] matrix, int rowStart, int rowEnd, int colStart, int colEnd) {

    int midRow = (rowStart + rowEnd) / 2;
    int minPos = findMin(matrix, midRow, colStart, colEnd);

    if (minPos >= (colStart + colEnd) / 2)
        colStart = (colStart + colEnd) / 2;
    else
        colEnd = (colStart + colEnd) / 2;

    if (matrix[midRow][minPos] < matrix[midRow + 1][minPos]
            && matrix[midRow][minPos] < matrix[midRow - 1][minPos]) {
        return matrix[midRow][minPos];
    } else if (matrix[midRow][minPos] > matrix[midRow + 1][minPos]) {
        return findLocalMinimum(matrix, midRow, rowEnd, colStart, colEnd);
    } else {
        return findLocalMinimum(matrix, rowStart, midRow, colStart, colEnd);
    }

}

private static int findMin(int[][] matrix, int midRow, int colStart, int colEnd) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int pos = -1;

    for (int i = colStart; i < colEnd; i++) {
        if (matrix[midRow][i] < min) {
            min = matrix[midRow][i];
            pos = i;
        }

    }

    return pos;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Best Case
    /*
     * int[][] matrix= { {1,-2,4,-6,1,8}, {-3,-6,-8,8,1,3}, {1,2,6,-2,-8,-6},
     * {-2,9,6,3,0,9}, {9,-1,-7,1,2,-6}, {-9,0,8,7,-6,9} };
     */

    // Two Iteration Down Case
    /*
     * int[][] matrix= { { 1,-2, 4,-6, 1, 8}, {-3,-6,-8, 8, 1, 3}, { 1, 2, 6, 9, 0,
     * 6}, {-2, 9, 6,-1,-1, 9}, { 9,-1,-7, 1, 2,-6}, {-9, 0, 8, 7,-6, 9} };
     */

    /*
     * //Left Down Case int[][] matrix= { { 1,-2, 4,-6, 0, 8}, {-3,-6,-8, 8,-2, 3},
     * {-2, 9, 6,-1, 1, 9}, { 1, 0, 6, 9, 2, 6}, { 9,-1,-7, 1, 2,-6}, {-9, 0, 8,
     * 7,-6, 9} };
     */

    int[][] matrix = { { 1, -2, 4, }, { -3, -6, -8, }, { -2, 9, 6, }

    };

    System.out.println(findLocalMinimum(matrix, 0, matrix.length, 0, matrix.length));

}
```

}

Comment: It works as Following 

1. Look for middle row of given matrix and find minimum out of it 
2. for that minimum look for above and below element to ensure that it's local minimu
3. if not restrict search matrix by 
 1. Row : choose half side of row in which the lesser element than middle row's element is. 
 2. colmun : choose the index at which minimum in the row was found.
4. Repeat step 1-3

Comment: The questions says the matrix consists of distinct integers, but I see repetitions in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a worst case time complexity of **O(n^2)**, then you could simply iterate over the entire matrix and find the smallest element that way - which kind of defeats the purpose because we are mereley looking for a local minimum.