# Algorithm Find local maximum in matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, find

I have a *n x n* matrix of mutually different elements. The algorithm should find a local maximum (value of actual element is bigger then his neighbours (up, down, left, right)). One local maximum is enough.

The final algorithm should be recursive. You can use only one operation: compare of neighbours. Algorithm should run in O(n).

I have try something like this:

```
FindMax(matrix, x, y)
{
 ...some code should be here...

 If(matrix[x+1,y] > matrix[x,y])
  FindMax(matrix, x+1, y)
 else if(matrix[x,y+1] > matrix[x,y])
  FindMax(matrix, x, y+1)
 ...
 some code
 ....
}
```

Input example:

> 1 2 3 
>  4 5 6 
>  7 8 9

9 is the result in O(n), n = number of rows or columns

Do you have tips how create the algorithm? Some help?

Comment: I try to start with first element (matrix[0,0]) and look if it has bigger neighbours. If it has, I pick the biggest neighbours a continue. If not then actual element is local maximum. Do you have better idea?

Comment: @User123456789: That approach is definitely not O(n)

Comment: Yes, it´s probably O(n*n)...can you tell me better approach?

Comment: @User123456789: No, I have no idea. It seems almost impossible to do deterministically

Comment: Do you have any kind of property that the matrix elements possess, for example some kind of monotonicity?

Comment: No, only elements in matrix should be muttualy different. [1, 1; 2, 3] is not valid matrix.

Comment: @User123456789: Can the elements be arbitrary large? or negative?

Comment: Yes, they can be. I think.

Comment: Are you restricted to use the part of code that you've shown and just change the ... parts or you can change them too?

Comment: @mok: I think he can do whatever he feels, but the only possible matrix operations are reading and comparing adjacent values

Comment: Is this question related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525179/find-local-minimum-in-n-x-n-matrix-in-on-time

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Yes it is, with just one more constraint that is using recursion. Minimum and maximum don't change anything here.

Comment: @NiklasB. With the ref. given by גלעדברקן now it's clear that he should use that code. And he should just do a greedy search that always results in a local optimum (with a finite N and mutually different elements)

Comment: @mok Greedy won't work, but the algorithm from the answer should :) Cool stuff

Comment: I would suggest closing this as an almost exact duplicate

Comment: @NiklasB. Well this is really very close to that question, but why do you think the answer from that link isn't greedy?

Comment: @mok: Yes it's greedy, but it's not the "obvious" greedy algorithm that OP uses here, which is quadratic

Comment: @NiklasB. Indeed it can be implemented with O(4*N) that is O(N).

Comment: @mok: Yes, I am aware of that. Not using gradient descent though, but using a much cleverer D&Q approach. I don't know what you're getting at here

Comment: So you recommend use as answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525179/find-local-minimum-in-n-x-n-matrix-in-on-time ?

Comment: Yes....................