# Peak element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

So I was trying to solve the following problem:

> Given an array of integers. Find a peak element in it. An array element is peak if it is NOT smaller than its neighbors. For corner elements, we need to consider only one neighbor. For example, for input array {5, 10, 20, 15}, 20 is the only peak element. For input array {10, 20, 15, 2, 23, 90, 67}, there are two peak elements: 20 and 90. Note that we need to return any one peak element.

from the following link: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-peak-in-a-given-array/

At one point they say

> If the middle element is smaller than the its left neighbor, then there is always a peak in left half.

I get confused at this point, how do we know for sure that there will be a peak element in left  half? All i can conclude from this is that there's atleast 1 element for sure that is bigger than its right neighbour (i.e a[m-1]) so there's a *chance* it could be the peak element) I have researched on stackoverflow and other sites but couldn't find a good explanation for the above stated conclusion

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is essentially the 1D version of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18525179/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you're standing on a middle element lower than its left neighbor:

```
            element
                         you
                       element
```

You look to your left. It looks like a hill.

Suppose you climb that hill. What do you see? Well, there are three possibilities:

```
1.
  element
              you
            element

                       element

2.
              you
  element   element

                       element

3.
              you
            element

  element              element
```

In cases 2 and 3, hooray! You've found a peak. In case 1, you keep climbing. Eventually, either you see an element that isn't higher than you, or you hit the left wall. In either case, you've found a peak.

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is important:

> For corner elements, we need to consider only one neighbor.

Let's see what happens when you iterate left from the middle element. We know the one to the left is larger. If the one to the left of *that* is smaller or equal, then you found a peak. If not, recurse.

That recursion has two possibilities: either you find a peak eventually, or you reach the end. If you reach the end then the element at the end is the largest you've found so far, therefore it is a peak by that corner element definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 * @author asharda
 *
 */
public class Peak {

  public int findPeakElement(int[] nums) {

    Integer[] num = new Integer[nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      num[i] = Integer.valueOf(nums[i]);
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(num));
    Collections.sort(list);
    int peak = list.get(list.size() - 1);
    int top = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
      if (nums[i] == peak) {
        top = i;
      }
    }

    return top;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int nums[] = {1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4};
    Peak p = new Peak();
    System.out.println(p.findPeakElement(nums));

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume nums[mid] < nums[mid-1] where nums is the array.
Given For corner cases, consider only 1 neighbor, its safe to assume that nums[-1] = -Infinity and nums[nums.size()] = -Infinity.

```
                          nums[mid-1]
                                      \  
                                        nums[mid]     


     /                                                                     \
 -Infinity                                                              Infinity
```

-Infinity must come from above as we can say that nums[0] and nums[nums.size()-1] are Finite.

Hence We can clearly see that Right side may or may not have peak, Consider the case when its strictly decreasing in right with no peak.

In Left Side:    nums[mid-1] might be peak if nums[mid-2] < nums[mid-1]
    else apply same condition moving one step left each time. You can notice that if above condition  -  True: Then You got a PEAK
                 - False: You will reach nums[0] and now it will be peak because nums[-1]
                          -Infinity and nums[0] is Finite, Hence You Got PEAK.