# Optimal way of checking the neighbours of an element in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I am given a matrix M with the dimensions n x n.

I must write an algorithm that returns a pair of x,y such that `Mx,y < min(Mx+1,y, Mx,y+1, Mx−1y, Mx,y−1).`

The first idea that you can come up with is of course take each element and then check the neighbours one by one to see if that relationship is true. However the algorithm has to be optimal from a time complexity point of view. Here I am unsure how to optimize.

Does anyone know the name of the algorithm that I can search or can give some pointers to how this algorithm might be optimized ?

I've given it a little more thought and I think that maybe this algorithm can be broken down to find the minimum in a matrix? that surely fulfills the relationship above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a local minimum. It's very easy to find by starting at some entry in the matrix and going to adjacent entries with a smaller value.

For example, if you start at `(x, y)` and `M[x+1, y] < M[x, y]`, then proceed at `(x+1, y)`. Then if `M[x+1, y-1] < M[x+1, y]`, then proceed at `(x+1, y-1)`. Repeat until the current value is a local minimum, which means you can no longer move to an adjacent smaller value.

Comment: Ah local minimum, yes yours is more efficient, I was thinking of the actual minimum at the moment which indeed would do more comparations. Thx nelfeal!

Comment: Look at [Find local minimum in n x n matrix in O(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525179/find-local-minimum-in-n-x-n-matrix-in-on-time) for a more general version, although this simple algorithm is `O(n)` for a matrix with random values.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! will give it a read before writing the code and will accept your answer as soon as I can